# Angular attach css class from parent component to children

Tags: angular

I want to pass a class that is conditionally applied to a parent component to children components.  Is there a way to do this without having to create my own Directive

Example:

Parent:

```
<app-myComponent [class.active]="activeState"></app-myComponent>
```

Child

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div **want to attach .active here if its on the parent**></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is the **@Input()** decorator which makes it possible to pass a state from parent to child. You need to import **Input** and **Component** from **'@angular/core';**

In your **child component** you have to prepare the process by adding this line of code:

`@Input() activeState: boolean;`

In the parent component you now can prepare the pass like this:

`<app-myComponent [activeState]="activeState" [class.active]="activeState></app-myComponent>`

Check out the documentation for Angular Input: [Inputs - Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass a class conditionally from a parent component to its child components is by using the @Input decorator in Angular.
In your parent component template, you can bind the **activeState** variable to the child component's active input property using property binding.

**Parent component**

```
<app-myComponent [active]="activeState"></app-myComponent>
```

**Child component**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div [class.active]="active"></div>
</div>
```

**Child component TypeScript**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myComponent',
  templateUrl: 'myComponent.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() active: boolean;
}
```